# HEAD request in PHP to validate (network not syntax) URLs?

Tags: php

Here is the [php.net listing](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-head.php) for http_head.

The function prototype is

```
string http_head ( string $url [, array $options [, array &$info ]] )
```

A list of `$options` is [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/http.request.options.php).

I want to use this to validate that a set of URLs is valid.

`[url1, url2, url3]`

Are there any options that should be set?  Is any of the `$info` relevant to should I just make sure that false is not returned instead of a string?

Comment: not sure about your question but have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url

Comment: @reikyoushin: By "valid" he means he wants to make sure the URL actually points somewhere real, and not to a broken location.

Comment: ahh ic, so he is invoking a get request and whatever is in the header will be validated. correct?

Comment: but how will it deal with valid URLs which currently have a server that is unreacheable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't need to set any of the `$options`, unless you're behind a proxy server or need to do something unusual. You probably should look through them just in case.

It's not likely you need to mess with `$info` unless you're debugging, since this gives you more complete visibility into the request and response.

Sample code:

```
foreach ($urls as $url) {
  $response = http_head($url);
  if ($response !== false) {
    # FIXME do something cool
  } else {
    # FIXME hey that url is broken!
  }
}
```

Comment: I've been writing JavaScript, which uses `in` instead of `as`, weird how language designers don't seem to communicate to make common idioms use the same syntax